# DIV not expanding when dynamic content is added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with the following CSS:

```
#feedback {
  min-height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

Then I add some content using `jQuery`.

```
jQuery('.feedback_text').html(feedback.message);
jQuery('.feedback_icon').addClass(feedback.type);
jQuery('#feedback').fadeIn('normal', function() {
  jQuery(this).height('100%');
});
```

The problem is that when I have more than one line of text, the DIV does not expand.

I've tried using `$('.feedback_text').height()`, but it only gives me the height specified in the CSS (24px) and not the height after dynamic content was added.

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: How you expect it to expand exactly?

Comment: Have you tried setting `height:auto;`?

Comment: have you tried removing line-height?

Comment: I've tried setting `height:auto` in tje jQuery, but that's not working. My goal is having the text inside the borders of the `DIV`.

Comment: What about `height:auto;` in the css?

Comment: @Steeven - nope, that did not help.

Comment: I am able to set height using `jQuery(this).height('50px');`, but I can't set a statick height. I must figure out how much space the new text takes.

Comment: That should work fine, and you shouldn't even need to set the height. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/1/ <-- Is there something you're doing differently from that example I just made?

Comment: @Matt Gibson - I've updated the code at jsfiddle. did that work? Now you see what my problem was.

Comment: @Steven Yes -- your problem is that both of your `<span>`s within the `<div>` are floated, which takes them out of the normal document flow, and stops the `<div>` expanding. I've [updated the fiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/6/), to add (a) the traditional solution, a non-floated div following the floats, with "clear" set via CSS, and removing the expicit height you had set on the feedback_text span. Next time, you might want to provide more complete code -- it was the floats that were causing the problem.

Comment: @Matt Gibson - Yeah, I didn't think of it at the time I posted the question. It only accured after I started testing different solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to set the height explicitly. Here's [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/1/) I just made, where you can see your code running and successfully showing a `<div>` expanded to fit the contents that are set.

Is there perhaps some other CSS rule affecting your div? What does it look like if you inspect it with a CSS debugger?

UPDATE: Thank you for providing [fuller code](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/4/). I see from this that your problem is that your container `<div>` only contains `float`ed elements. Floated elements are taken out of the normal document flow, and don't affect the height of their container like they normally would. (And also because you've set an explicit height on your `.feedback_text` element, which I'm guessing you didn't mean to do.)

The traditional hack/fix for this is to add a final contained element (which can be empty) below the floated elements, set to `clear` the floats. That forces the containing element to stretch to fit the floated elements. So, you go from this:

```
...
#feedback span { float: left }
...
<div id="feedback">
    <span class="feedback_icon"></span>
    <span class="feedback_text"></span>
</div>
```

to this:

```
...
#feedback span { float: left }
.clearfix { clear: both }
...
<div id="feedback">
    <span class="feedback_icon"></span>
    <span class="feedback_text"></span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

..and everything should start working. I've updated your example to use this technique [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/7/).

By the looks of what you want to achieve, though, I'm not sure you need to float both elements anyway. Floating the image left and leaving the text non-floating, together with a few other adjustments, lets you get the effect you want but without the clearfix hack. [Here's my final example](http://jsfiddle.net/AuGPd/11/) (note I've fiddled with your images, etc., to get a working example.)

**UPDATE**: I just came back to this answer after an upvote, and I feel I should share the [more modern solution](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) to expanding block elements to contain their floats, which is to add a simple `overflow: hidden;` to the container. This trick works in all modern browsers, though some may also require a set width, and is probably the simplest way of expanding the `div` to contain the floats in this question.

I've [updated my example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/AuGPd/115/) to show this working. All it needed was the `overflow` property on the `feedback` div for it to work for all my browsers. According to that article, you might need to set an explicit height or width (e.g. `width: 100%;`) for some versions of Opera or IE, but I'd recommend you give it a blast without it and see if it works in the browswers you're targeting before bothering with that.

```
#feedback {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the callback function does not refer to `jQuery('#feedback')` object. Try to cache it before using.

use this:

```
var feedBackDiv = $('#feedback');
feedBackDiv.fadeIn('normal', function(){
    feedBackDiv.css({'height':'100%'});
});
```

Also consider that div element is a `block box`, meaning that gets all the available horizontal space of parent, and wrapping the content vertically (stretching vertically to provide space for child elements). So, unless you haven't encountered the [great collapse](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/), you don't need to specify a height for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

As it turned out, the `feedback_text` element was a `span` element. Changing this to a `div` and adding the following style `display: inline-block` solved my problem.

Thanks for helping me along the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without explicitly specifying height? DIVs usually auto size to hold the entire content unless the content is floated or absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be related to the display property set to none.

Try to use another method to hide the element, for example you could set its height to 0 in the css, and then set it back to auto later when the content has been added.

Or, if you don't care about the size of the element you could use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.